# Newly adding md-input-container is showing as invalid

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

On submitting the form and adding new md-input-container textboxes dynamically, it is showing text box in red color but as the user hasn't touched the textbox, it should show in default color. 
Please find the issue here:
[Code pen link here](http://codepen.io/ashok123osm/pen/YpRLEd)

HTML:

```
 <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" class="inputdemoErrors" ng-app="MyApp">

  <md-content layout-padding="">
    <form name="projectForm" novalidate>

      <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-repeat="dep in depFiles">
        <label>Description</label>
        <input md-maxlength="30" required="" md-no-asterisk="" name="description" ng-model="project.description">
        <div ng-messages="projectForm.description.$error">
          <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
          <div ng-message="md-maxlength">The description must be less than 30 characters long.</div>
        </div>
      </md-input-container>


      <div>
        <md-button type="button" ng-click="addNew();">Add Row</md-button>
        <md-button type="submit">Submit</md-button>
      </div>

      <p style="font-size:.8em; width: 100%; text-align: center;">
        Make sure to include <a href="https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages" target="_blank">ngMessages</a> module when using ng-message markup.
      </p>
    </form>
  </md-content>

</div>

<!--
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. 
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be foundin the LICENSE file at http://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/license.
-->
```

JS:

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
/*  $scope.project = {
    description: 'Nuclear Missile Defense System',
    rate: 500
  };*/
  $scope.addNew = addNew;
          $scope.depFiles = [];
        addNew();
        function addNew(){
        $scope.depFiles.push({
           name: ''
       });
        }

});
```

Click on Submit and then click on Add row, for newly added textbox, it is showing red color, but it should not show.
Any kind of help is appreciable. On click on submit and then add row, How it can be shown in default color i.e., not in red color.

Answer (score 0):

When you add an input in your form, you will not have to change the name, in the error message will always have that red color because they refer to the same name

```
 <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-repeat="dep in depFiles">
        <label>Description</label>
        <input md-maxlength="30" required="" md-no-asterisk="" name="description" ng-model="project.description">
//
// yours name is equals in all
//
        <div ng-messages="projectForm.description.$error">
//
// Will always have the same error if you do not change the name for each input
//
          <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
          <div ng-message="md-maxlength">The description must be less than 30 characters long.</div>
        </div>
      </md-input-container>
```

Comment: I have updated the name to change it dynamically. Now, the name differs for each record. It is still not working to show newly added textbox in default color instead of red. I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: I have added my code in code pen. You can find it here.
http://codepen.io/ashok123osm/pen/YpRLEd